# how can I parse json with a single line python command?

Tags: python, json

I would like to use python to parse JSON in batch scripts, for example:

```
HOSTNAME=$(curl -s "$HOST" | python ?)
```

Where the JSON output from curl looks like:

```
'{"hostname":"test","domainname":"example.com"}'
```

How can I do this with a single line python command?

Comment: Much easier to use something like `jq` from the command line, which is dedicated to parsing JSON and so has a cleaner design: `HOSTNAME=$(curl -s $HOST | jq -r '.hostname')`.

Comment: Down voters, please state why you are down voting.  It's difficult to improve questions if you don't know what's wrong with them.

Comment: @chepner true, but I don't have and can't install jq on the host in question, but I do have python and the json module.

Comment: For what purpose do you require the Python code to be "a single line"?

Comment: It's much easier to work with single line commands in a batch script.  Multi line Python statements that require Python indentation are difficult to integrate into scripts using pipes and redirects without having to put the Python statements into a separate file as a Python script.

Comment: Doing this in Python is an excellent question and doesn't deserve a downvote. (Also, handy command-line utilities like `jq` exist, so any Python solution will be somewhat more flabby than `jq`).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Based on the JSON below being returned from the curl command ...

```
'{"hostname":"test","domainname":"example.com"}'
```

You can then use python to extract the hostname using the python json module:

```
HOSTNAME=$(curl -s "$HOST" |
  python -c \
    'import json,sys;print(json.load(sys.stdin)["hostname"])')
```

Note that I have split the line using a `\` to make it more readable on stackoverflow.  I've also simplified the command based on [chepner's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) comment.

Original source: [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

See also: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Powerful%20Python%20One-Liners

Comment: For a one-liner, I wouldn't bother with the intermediate variable `obj`: `python -c 'import json,sys;print json.load(sys.stdin)["hostname"]`.

Comment: For python3: `python3 -c 'import json,sys; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["hostname"])'`. Same thing but with parens for print

Comment: This answer, while technically correct, is not conveniently formatted with executable code snippets. For instance most people are more interested in parsing the JSON, than in making a curl call to a service running on particular host. (I tried to edit it for clarity, but was rejected.)

Answer (score 14):

```
echo '{"hostname":"test","domainname":"example.com"}' | python -m json.tool
```

Comment: This only prettily prints the incoming json.  There is no extraction of variables or array members.

Comment: echo '{"hostname":"test","domainname":"example.com"}' | python -m json.tool | awk '/hostname/{ printf $2 }' | tr --delete '"'

Answer (score 6):

Since Python is multiplatform, is important to note differences between Linux and Windows, especially because of how they treat double-quotes/single-quotes differently.

Second, some previous answers are a little bit obsolete: in python2, `print` without parentheses was permitted. Nevertheless, in python3, print must be between parentheses.

### **Linux (bash)**

It doesn't matter how you put double/single quotes. Json can be parsed in both ways with "keys" or 'keys'

```
HOSTNAME=$(curl -s "$HOST" |
  python3 -c 'import json,sys;print(json.load(sys.stdin)["hostname"])')
```

It also works: (**pay attention at single/double quote at key**)

```
HOSTNAME=$(curl -s "$HOST" |
  python3 -c "import json,sys;print(json.load(sys.stdin)['hostname'])")
```

### **Windows (powershell)**

Keys in json MUST be between single quotes. Only the following syntax is accepted.
The `ConvertTo-Json` function generates object and works with keys between single quotes.

```
$HOSTNAME=(Invoke-RestMethod $HOST | `
  ConvertTo-Json | `
  python3 -c "import json,sys; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['hostname'])")
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer to my question.  Up voted.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
$ python -m json.tool
```

It reads input from stdin and print out in a nicely.
So with your questions:

```
HOSTNAME=$(curl -s "$HOST" | python -m json.tool )
```